# Should we keep the pokemon-special tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, lumping-and-splitting

Since January 16, 2013 the [pokemon-special](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-special) tag was used only twice and both times the question was also tagged with the [pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon) tag. So it made me wonder what the point was of keeping this tag around. Especially since the [pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon) tag includes mangas based on the game, which pokemon adventures comes closest too iirc.

[pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon)

> Pokémon is originally a japanese video game, made by GAME FREAK Inc.. Because of the popularity, soon there was an anime and multiple manga-series published.
>
> Questions regarding Pokémon, **especially the manga** and the anime. Questions about the story of the game are allowed, but for gameplay-specific questions please ask at Arqade.SE.

[pokemon-special](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-special)

> "Pokémon Special" (also, "Pokémon Adventures") is one of the manga interpretations of the Pokémon series. For other questions about Pokémon, see [pokemon].

---

I removed the tags from the two only posts that were using them, in order for the tag to be removed. If I was wrong in doing so, these were the two posts tagged accordingly.

- [What did Team Rocket use to evolve Rhyhorn?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/what-did-team-rocket-use-to-evolve-rhyhorn)
- [Are there any relations between the different "sagas" in Pokémon Special/Pokémon Adventures manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/434/are-there-any-relations-between-the-different-sagas-in-pok%C3%A9mon-special-pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: I agree, lots of other series are done by their master title, such as soul eater and soul eater not

Comment: Unless there are many more questions that require this clarification, I don't think the use of a more specific tag is necessary.

Comment: Given the use of the *FMA* tag to cover *Brotherhood*, the manga, and the original anime, I think removing this tag was fine.